# No class located error in Matlab while calling java class

Tags: java, matlab, static-functions

I have developed an Matlab code for stegnography which requires some preprocessing to be done by a Java file.

The java file `aes1.java` contains the function `encrypt(String s)` which needs to be called by matlab code:

```
javaaddpath('C:\Users\Aneesh\Desktop\BE_Project');
disp(char(javaMethod('hash', 'aes1', userText)));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error using javaMethod
No class aes1 can be located on the Java class path
Error in project_mod (line 11)
disp(char(javaMethod('hash','aes1',userText)));"
```

Versions I'm using:

- Matlab `2013a`
- Java `1.6`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Update:**

I have a `.jar` file which contains all the classes i need. I've imported it and tried using it but I'm still getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the documentation. `javaaddpath` adds one or more folders of java Archive (**jar**) files.

You need to compile your java file to a class-file and add it using `javaclasspath`

Comment: I archived the class file into a jar file and imported it. But still I am facing the same problem